# How to include the google OR-tools in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, constraint-programming, or-tools

I am using the Linux machine, IntelliJ as the IDE for development. I need to include the Google OR-tools in the spring boot application. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Add the below dependency in POM.xml in  tag. Change the version you need.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.ortools</groupId>
    <artifactId>ortools</artifactId>
    <version>v2015-09</version>
</dependency>
```

Run mvn clean install

Comment: It is not in the maven central Repo, It is in ICM repo When I configure for the ICM repo, Still, it couldn't resolve the artifact.

Comment: The problem is that when you'll create a fat jar, it will not work, since you'll not be able to load the or-tools native libs: https://github.com/magneticflux-/ortools-java/issues/5#issuecomment-623245302